# How to close a UserControl View in mvvm-light?

Tags: .net, mvvm-light

I've craeted a sample with mainView and 2 other views (usercontrols).
I've placed a button "close" on the child view and i want to close that view.
there is a command attached to that button, and when close is pressed i ask the ViewModelLocator to clean it.

BUt- the view still being displayed..
What i'm doing wrong? 
How can i close a userControl view with mvvm-light?

```
    private RelayCommand _closeCommand;
    public RelayCommand CloseCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_closeCommand == null)
            {
                _closeCommand = new RelayCommand(()=>
                   ViewModelLocator.ClearAllChannels(),

                   );
            }
            return _closeCommand;
        }

    }
```

ViewModelLocator function:

```
    public static void ClearAllChannels()
    {
        if (_allChannels != null)
        {
            _allChannels.Cleanup();
            _allChannels = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModelLocator does not actually host your views. It just provides a way to look up the ViewModel that supports a particular view.

So you need to ask the control that hosts your views (probably a Window or Frame) to close them.