# Exiting an App or Closing a Control When Using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

In my WPF application, I am using the `ViewModelLocator` without IoC.  I am calling the static `ViewModelLocator.Cleanup()` method provided by the MVVM-Light framework from my own button which is tied to a "close window command".  This Command calls the static `ViewModelLocator.Cleanup()`, which calls an instance Cleanup() method on my MainWindowViewModel instance.  The instance Cleanup() method then sets the property to which the MainWindow binds its `DataContext`, to null.  The setter on the property raises a `PropertyChanged` event.  Curiously, setting this property to null does not cause the window to close.

I am trying to understand why this is the case?  If I set the MainWindow's `DataContext` to null, should that not be the same as `Window.Close()`?  In my case, the Window and all of its elements remain on the screen.  However, if I attempt further actions, I get null pointer exceptions, indicating the `DataContext` binding Property has indeed been set to null;  this has also been confirmed in the debugger.

I have created a workaround by hooking the Application.Exit event and issuing a Window.Close() in the event handler in order to create my own "Close Window" button (ie, to create same functionality for my own Button / Command as clicking the X button in the upper right of a Window).  Since calling a UI element (ie, the Window instance) from MVVM directly is not MVVM friendly, I used a [ViewService](http://blog.synctank.com/2011/12/03/viewservice-present/) to implement the Window.Close() functionality in order to keep the workaround MVVM friendly.  I am a big fan of the ViewService idiom (or pattern), but I just don't think it should be necessary here; except, I could see how exiting the app is a special case that perhaps should tie-in with the application lifecycle, and .Net seems to only allow exiting a WPF app by issuing the Window.Close() method.

Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: I dont know what your question is, but closing a window by setting its Datacontext to null sounds rather unintuitive and not very useful

Comment: @flq: Do you agree that "closing" other visual elements, like a UserControl, is routinely done by setting the property that binds its DataContext to its ViewModel, to null?  I was taking the same approach to closing the Window / exiting the app; seemed like the right way to exit an app from a ViewModel (thereby staying MVVM friendly).  Of course, setting the Prop to null follows any clean-up that may be appropriate.  I guess my question is, simply, how would you exit an mvvm-light app, if you wanted to implement your own exit button?

Comment: Is this way of closing views MVVM-light-specific behaviour ?

Comment: No, but upon some further thought, perhaps it is a more common technique when a DataTemplate is inflated based upon a DataType (eg, <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type XyzViewModel}">...</DataTemplate>) - and subsequently deflated by setting the XyzViewModel to null - than it is to UserControls or other Controls.

Comment: If you think about it, this is not a closing of the view. It is still there but may not take up space in rendering. However, an inspection of the visual tree should reveal that the view is still there

Comment: @flq:  I guess I may not know the proper way to close any control and release its View and ViewModel resources.  I thought the proper way would be perform any Cleanup / Save on the control's content, and then set the ViewModel to null.  At that point, I thought WPF would take care of cleaning up the memory that was used by the View elements, and my setting the ViewModel to null would allow the garbage collector to re-claim the ViewModel's memory. I am starting to feel like I may be missing something basic here.

Comment: @flq: This [stackoverflow article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042741/how-to-close-a-usercontrol-view-in-mvvm-light) discusses the issue a bit, but I am not sure I follow how to "close" a UserControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer to my original question, in addition to the one raised in my comments discussion with flq.

First, the answer to the original question is that the proper way to close the Window is along the lines of what I did in my described "workaround".  Closing an app is a View-initiated process, as it is the Window control that has the bits for how to do it.  You can of course hook the Application.Exit event so that you can perform cleanup on your ViewModels, prompt the user to save data, etc..

The question raised by me after some interesting discussion with flq is, if I don't just set a control's `DataContext` (ie, ViewModel) to null in order to release the View and ViewModel resources, how should I do it?

An interesting discussion with some nuances can be found [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/53148.aspx), but the basic answer is that you find the parent control and remove the control you want to close from its Children list.  Note, this is a different technique with a different goal than just making the control not visible by setting is Visibility property to Collapsed.  In the following example, "this" is the control to be removed (ie, "Closed"):

```
Panel p = (Panel) this.Parent;
p.Children.Remove(this);
```

I am not sure if you still need to then set the child (ie, "this") to null to re-claim its resources, or, if just removing it from the visual tree will cause WPF to re-claim the resources; the above linked discussion makes no mention.  As mentioned in the original [discussion](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/53148.aspx), the above technique can be supplemented by hooking it to certain events, or using other application specific logic.